# Absolute positioned element fill the rest of height

Tags: css

I have `<pre>` element inside `<div>`. This `<div>` is absolute positioned with width and height set to 100%. Sometimes height of `<pre>` element is larger than main `<div>` so it jumps out of page.
How can I set this `<pre>` element so it fills the rest of height without jumping out of page

```
<div class="window">

<pre class="prettyprint code"><xmp>

...some large piece of code

</xmp></pre>

CSS

.window{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
        display: inline-block;
}

.code{
    left: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    width: auto;
}
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/F6YAK/

Comment: You won't be able to do this with CSS alone. You'll need to use some JavaScript to calculate the sizes.

Comment: Can you drop an image of what you are expecting?

Comment: I expect either to expand .window so it covers all code in pre tag, or to set pre tag to take the rest of height, and to add scrollbar if it tries to jump out of page. If I set height of pre tag to 100% than it has height greater than the page itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest 2 solutions

**Solution 1**

Make the `<pre>` element scrollable by adding `overflow:auto;` to `.code` and giving it a height so it dosesn't overflow the parent div (`window`)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F6YAK/15/)**

**Solution 2**

Make the whole window scrollable by adding `overflow:auto;` to `.window`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F6YAK/16/)**

Comment: Solution 1 is not ok for me because .code should have variable height, and solution 2 is closest to what I did to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can hide this text using

```
overflow: hidden
```

in parent div. Or you can add scrollbars using:

```
overflow: scroll
```

in parent div

Comment: I updated my question with fiddle so you'll understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You should position the `pre` element with something like this :

```
width: calc(100% - 250px);
height: calc(100% - 70px);
```

It does not take into account default margins though.
You could make use of `box-sizing: border-box` as well.

Is that what you needed ?

Comment: You could use, on the `pre` element, `bottom: 0` and `right: 0` too.

Comment: This is what I need, I tried this before, but since calc is not supported in Opera (not sure about IE) I don't prefer using calc